# PHP parse error of variable

Tags: php

I want to create variable with \ value, but I have parse error. It's just simple line:

```
<?php
$var = "\";
?>
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: You need to escape it first. Use this: $var = "\\";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\`character is used to tell php to treat the symbol after it as text and not code. 
The question now is what to do if you want the actual character `\` in your text? It's simple, just escape it. The following code should work:

```
<?php
$var = "\\";
?>
```

You're escaping the `\` with a `\` if that makes any sense. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Escape it by adding a second `\`

```
<?php
$var = "\\";
?>
```

`\` is the char used to escape things in a string, some examples:

```
 $var = "\"";
 $javascript = "getElementById(\"id\")";
```

Comment: But i need only one slash.

Comment: @Nitor, echo the value of `$var`. It should only show the one `\\`. <- I'm even escaping the comment formatting :p

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote

> $var = '\'

The caracther \ escape other caracther, forma \n, \r or \t